# ImportError: No module named 'queue' while running my app freezed with cx_freeze

Tags: python, import, python-3.4, cx-freeze

I am using python 3.4. I am able to run my python script without any problem.
But While running my freezed python script , following error have appeared. 
I am able to freeze my script successfully too with cx_freeze.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\utils>utils.exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\__init__.py", line 27, i
n <module>
    from . import urllib3
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .connectionpool import (
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 28, in <module>
    from .packages.six.moves.queue import LifoQueue, Empty, Full
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\packages\six.py", line 203, in load_module
    mod = mod._resolve()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\packages\six.py", line 115, in _resolve
    return _import_module(self.mod)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\packages\six.py", line 82, in _import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named 'queue'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\__startup__.py", line 12, in <module>
    __import__(name + "__init__")
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\Console.py", line 21, in <module>
    scriptModule = __import__(moduleName)
  File "utils.py", line 3, in <module>
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\requests\__init__.py", line 63, in <module>
    from . import utils
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\requests\utils.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ._internal_utils import to_native_string
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\requests\_internal_utils.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .compat import is_py2, builtin_str
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\requests\compat.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .packages import chardet
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
    import urllib3
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\urllib3\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .connectionpool import (
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 28, in <module>
    from .packages.six.moves.queue import LifoQueue, Empty, Full
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\urllib3\packages\six.py", line 203, in load_module
    mod = mod._resolve()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\urllib3\packages\six.py", line 115, in _resolve
    return _import_module(self.mod)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\urllib3\packages\six.py", line 82, in _import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named 'queue'
```

Even tried installing package 'six' with no help.
My setup.py is 
    from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
    import requests.certs

```
setup(
name = "utils" ,
version = "0.1" ,
description = " utils for accounts" ,
executables = [Executable("utils.py")],
options = {"build_exe": {"packages": ["urllib", "requests"],"include_files":[(requests.certs.where(),'cacert.pem')]}},
```

)

script  imports following module

```
import requests
import urllib.request
import uuid
import json
import http.client
from xml.dom import minidom
```

Any help will be highly appreciated. please see me as novice in python

Comment: I am having the exact same problem. Did u figure it out?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I had the same issues running on Ubuntu with Python 3.5. It seems that `cx_freeze` has problems with libraries that import other files or something like that.

Importing `Queue` together with `requests` worked for me, so:

```
import requests
from multiprocessing import Queue
```

And I don't think specifying `urllib` in `"packages": ["urllib", "requests"]` is necessary.

Comment: in setup.py, options={"build_exe": {"packages": ["multiprocessing"]}} can also do the trick (I'm running cx_Freeze 6.0b1)

Answer (score 4):

There are Several options based on project packages:

Method1:

> Answer: I solve the problem my issue was I had file named queue.py in the same
>   directory

Method2:
Queue is in the multiprocessing module so:

```
from multiprocessing import Queue
```

Method3:
 Updating pip from 1.5.6 to 8.1.2

```
`sudo python -m pip install -U pip`
```

Reboot system (don't know if necessary, but only after reboot new version of pip was listed)
Method4:

from six.moves.queue import Queue  //I don't know how u import six package

Answer (score 4):

In setup.py, `options={"build_exe": {"packages": ["multiprocessing"]}}` can also do the trick.

Comment: At least with cx_Freeze 6.0b1

Answer (score 1):

In addition to

```
from multiprocessing import Queue
```

I rolled back to the older version of cx_freeze:

```
pip install cx-freeze==4.3.3
```

Besides, the "requests" library complained on absence of "urllib3" module. I upgraded this to *requests==2.13.0* and all now works.

I'm using Python 3.4 on Win10. Hope this will help.

Comment: I tried "pip install cx-freeze==4.3.3" Now I cant even use cx_freeze:
"No module named cx_freeze"  PLEASE HELP.
How do I turn it back to the latest version?!

Comment: pip install cx-freeze --upgrade